# React render return statements with () vs return with nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have a question regarding the difference between

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
          <Container></Container>
        </div>
        )
      }
};

export default Home
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return 
        <div>
          <Container></Container>
        </div>

      }
};

export default Home
```

Note the parentheses after return, if I don't have the parentheses I get a compile error

Comment: Second method has an unused JSX expression after the `return`

Comment: I'm not sure what that means exactly, what is an unused JSX expression?

Comment: An unused expression (though this time it's in JSX syntax). In the second snippet, you're returning `undefined` immediately